# How to fix " TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable "?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Rolling a custom estimator to explore RNN prediction in a time series, I'm unable to turn the 'features' argument of my model function into a sequence, for supply 
to:

```
tf.nn.static_rnn(
    cell,
    inputs,
    initial_state=None,
    dtype=None,
    sequence_length=None,
    scope=None
)
 (2nd parameter).
```

I need the following to work in order to turn "features" (the dictionary returned from my input function) into a sequence of time steps:

```
x = tf.split(features['f1'], 8, 1)
```

This is my model fn abbreviated:

```
    def rnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):  
        # 0. Reformat input shape to become a sequence; i.e. break it into the series time steps
        x   = tf.split(features['f1'], 8, 1)

        # 1. configure the RNN
        lstm_cell  = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(LSTM_SIZE)
        outputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
...
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\19\IronCondorTrade\ICondorIV.py", line 124, in <module>
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 473, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 613, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\training.py", line 714, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 367, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1158, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1188, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1146, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "E:\19\IronCondorTrade\ICondorIV.py", line 18, in rnn_model_fn
    x   = tf.split(features['f1'], 8, 1)
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

The error occurs when I run the code (from inside IDLE). I expect it to proceed to building the RNN network but instead gets stuck with - TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable - . Tried various ways of getting at the features argument but they all return with the same type of message that what I'm thinking is a dictionary, is instead a function; mystifying enough to be my first SO post. Any guidance deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is the error with trace? Does `static_rnn` return a function (`outputs`)?

Comment: I think some of your code is missing here. Can you post the complete stack trace and the actual lines of code where the error originates from?

Comment: I missed that first line. What's `features`? Show how this function is called.

Comment: Recall the general estimator input_fn, which returns both `features` and `labels` via `make_one_shot_iterator.get_next()`; that is what `features` is, passed from the input function to the model function.

Comment: I would guess the problem is where `rnn_model_fn` is called: it seems the `features` argument received is a function rather than a dictionary. So it would help a lot if you showed the call to `rnn_model_fn` and how its parameters are being built.

Comment: Thanks joanis - that call is internal and listed in the stack trace (see the 2nd to last line). It is called from line 1146 in estimator.py, completely outside my control.